# How to find particular references is use in which project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

i am facing below warning but not able to find out that

Newtonsoft.Json.dll version 7 is use in which project.

> ```
> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
> File name: 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'
>   at TTIAsyncCOMInterop.Logging.Logger.Log[T](T obj)
>   at TTIAsyncCOMInterop.OperationCall.CreateOperation() in D:\Build\System\TTI Services\TTIAsyncCOMService\TTIAsyncCOMInterop\OperationCall.cs:line 78
>   at TTIAsyncCOMInterop.OperationCall.Execute(AsyncApplicationTrace applicationTraceForCall) in D:\Build\System\TTI Services\TTIAsyncCOMService\TTIAsyncCOMInterop\OperationCall.cs:line 35
>   at TTIAsyncCOMInterop.QueuedProcessor.processCall(Object i) in D:\Build\System\TTI Services\TTIAsyncCOMService\TTIAsyncCOMInterop\Program.cs:line 1674
> ```

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.

Comment: What project is `TTIAsyncCOMInterop` in?

Comment: this project is mainly use for start/stop  the service

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: yes but actually i am not able to search that this Newtonsoft.Json.DLL is use in which Project.      and about your QUE.  out product is big thats why i am not able to find out about TTIAsyncCOMInterop.

Comment: This really lacks sufficient information. What version are you referencing? What version is actually copied to your output folder? What does your assembly redirects in your project folder look like? Do you have any other libraries that depend on newtonsoft.Json? Are you using nuget?

Comment: The path to TTIAsyncCOMInterop is mentioned in the stack. That should help locate it in your solution. You can't fix dependency problems without understanding your solution. And understanding means at least the structure and where things are.

Comment: What version of Newtonsoft do you use? Why would something be lookign for such an old version of 7 might be a better question. Remove that old code with fresh new code and resolve the issue.

Comment: This error message usually indicates that the version specified in the project does not match the version available at runtime. If you are using an older version of Visual Studio that relies on packages.config to manage NuGet packages, make sure you specify the correct version of Newtonsoft.Json in your packages.config file.